# What kinds of vibrato arms do what’s described in this video?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, tuning, guitar-effects, tremolo-system

I have no luck searching for the kind of vibrato arm, or tremolo arm or whammy bar Steve Vai seems to describe in this video at 3:20

He seems to describe a vibrato arm that keeps the intervals of chords perfectly in tune - or tries to better than other alternatives. But it seems everyone on the internet needs help keeping their regular vibrato arms in tune.

Can anyone point me to whammy bars that do this or how I can search for it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TransTrem

Comment: @ToddWilcox - that seems to be another system with Steinberger at the helm. I reckon Vai's is in conjunction with the electronic tuning system.

Answer (score 1):

As @ToddWilcox says, that is an advertised feature of the Steinberger Transtrem, but for the life of me, that looks like a Kahler bridge, which was Betamax to the Floyd Rose's VHS in the 80s. They still exist but didn't win.

The midi pickup and tuning control remind me of a Strat that Fender released years ago, but I don't think that has much to do with the whammy bar's effect, but I don't know.

I'm not seeing this guitar on Vai's website.